# Assembly as a First Programming Language?

Tags: programming-languages, assembly

How good of an idea do you think it would be to teach people Assembly (some variant) as a first programming language? It would take a lot more effort than learning for instance Java or Python, but one would have good understanding of the machine more or less from "programming day one" (compared to many higher level languages, at least). What do you think? Is it a realistic idea, at least to those who are ready to make the extra effort? Advantages and disadvantages?

*Note: I'm no teacher, just curious*

Comment: I think its better suited to people studying computer science and not software engineering / development

Comment: @Imran I agree in principal, but every college-level program I can think of has degrees in Computer Science which are earned by people who mostly go on to work in Software Engineering. (I'm assuming this question is about a serious basis for a programming career, not e.g. a high-school survey course)

Comment: @Imran - I found that a little surprising. Computer science is surely more leaning towards mathematics and theory? More interested in sets, abstract algebras and asymptotic notation than in bit-fiddling and writing endless repetitions of move-blah-to-blah.

Comment: Computer Science certainly has abstracts subjects, but it's also very "close to the hardware" in some respects. I once attended LICS, a Computer Science conference. I remember it had papers about data locality of various sorting algorithms which I imagine gives theoretical foundations to the study of practical efficiency of algorithms. Regarding assembly, I personally find it has some resemblance to some theoretical computation models (Turing machines, counter machines...)

Comment: Every programmer should at least read about how assembly works, IMO. It gave me a lot of insight and I'm typically about as not-close-to-the-chrome as you can get. Jeff Duntemann's Assembly Language Step by Step is a fun read for beginners.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be difficult to inspire a new programmer with assembly code. A dynamic hello, user website is much cooler with less effort. I'm not saying that the fundamental lessons are the same, but an introductory course is going to have a large inspirational content, or else there won't be a second course.

I remember my early programming courses were taught in Scheme and I was mostly frustrated that I couldn't easily just compile to an .exe and "run" my program (I thought MS Visual Basic was the end-all of programming). It wasn't until years later that I really grasped what a powerful tool I had been playing with. I think that I would have appreciated it more and gotten those lessons down better if I'd had some early experience in something a little more pragmatic at first.

Comment: I've seen many students who were vastly more amazed making an LED blink and a motor move.

Comment: @Whatsisname +1, that would make a nice impressive demo, as long as it can be done without getting caught up in the electronics. Of course, that could be done with a higher-level language too i.e. Roomba hacking, if the "driver" were an instructor-provided black box.

Comment: Plenty of new programmers were inspired by assembly on the VIC20, C=64 and similar machines.

Comment: @Gaius Not at first! You turn on those machines and you're in a basic interpreter. Assembly comes in after a fair amount of experience and hitting the limits of what basic can do...

Comment: @whatsisname but you can use something like an Arduino to blink LEDs and move motors without having to learn assembly

Comment: I don't think making motors move or LEDs blink is the point; the point is knowing that there are (almost) nothing thats done for you. When making a 'dynamic user website' a lot, almost everything in fact, of what happens is done for you - it's not something YOU did. When you get down to assembly level you do all the hard work yourself, and this is extremely rewarding.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's a *terrible* idea for both Software Engineering and CS students, and generally anyone more interested in programming than in electronics.

It *can* be done, but it doesn't mean it *should* be done. Back in the day, the way to do really cool stuff with home computers was to learn assembly first. That was because of early hardware limitations -- higher level languages just weren't powerful and fast enough. Nowadays, you can do much cooler stuff, in a shorter time, with a higher-level language.

What sounds more interesting, writing a fast prototype for a simple game and toying with variations on an algorithm, or struggling with registers and low-level stuff?

Comment: As a pianist, I'd certainly have found it more interesting to jump right in with some songs, but to become decent you need to practice arpeggios, scales, etc.  And then to do really groundbreaking stuff (playing with "prepared pianos" and the like) you need to know how the piano works from the inside out.  It's all how well you want to know your craft.

Comment: @John at CashCommons: Bad analogy.  Starting with assembler is like starting the hammers, keyboard, weights and dampers.  And then moving on to music theory (circle of fifths) to explain the black-key, white-key business.  Then moving on to yet more music theory before playing a scale.

Comment: @John: practicing arpeggios, scales, etc, is _exactly_ what you do when you play with a higher level language. Struggling with registers, instruction cycles and the hardware is outside the realm of piano playing.

Comment: @S.Lott: Ehhhhh ... don't quite buy that.  I can write a "hello world" type program in assembly without worrying about transistors.  One doesn't need to be a chip designer to be a programmer.  The knowledge you're talking about would be foundations for building or repairing a piano, which is only cursorily related to playing one.

Comment: @John at CashCommons: "building or repairing a piano".  That's the analogy with assembler.  A trivial "hello world" in assembler **can** be written, but it's just OS API calls -- in effect ignoring all the horrifying details of assembler.  For writing I/O drivers, assembler is essential.  Same way the hammers and dampers are about building and maintaing, not performing.

Comment: @S.Lott:  Hmmmm ... I guess the particular instruction set does depend on the chip, doesn't it?  Good point.

Comment: Back in the early days of home computers, it was worthwhile learning BASIC first and then assembler, since that way you could write the time-consuming parts in assembler.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's a terrible idea, but just how complex a program are you going to give these students? Assembly takes a lot more work. It might be OK to start them with for very basic stuff and then move them to something that's easier to work in, once they've gotten an appreciation for working at the lower level. First-time students sometimes get ideas in their head they'll code the next Halo, or MS Office or AutoCAD or something, and when they see how much work goes into a *simple* assembly language, they could be scared off, so make it clear that there's better things than assembly and then move them to that once they've seen the concepts. You could also try teaching assemlby concurrent with something else like C.

Also, which assembly language? I somewhat recall MIPS was relatively easy to work in, and I think it runs in an emulator so no danger of causing problems to the *real* machine, though there may be better tools than that now.

This *could* work well, if it's done right. Just be careful...

Comment: +1 for the complexity of the problem thing. My vote would be to contrast a few assembler implementations against higher-level language implementations. And maybe use e.g. 68000 assembler in an emulator rather than x86 - I don't know how x86/amd64 assembler has evolved, but the 68000 was much cleaner and easier to work with than 8086 way-back-then. Also perhaps worth considering - a virtual machine assembler such as you can get with LLVM. Not the same as real assembler, but it shares a lot of similar principles, and is probably more relevant.

Comment: Teaching ASM concurrently with C sounds like a pretty good idea

Comment: @Steve314:  I'm not up on x86 assembler, but it looks like it's gotten more complicated than 8086.

Comment: @David - I expect so, but it may well have got simpler in some ways. In the 8086 days, the range of address modes available depended on which particular register you were using, as well as on the instruction. On 68000, there were (for most purposes) data registers and address registers, with each type used pretty uniformly, with no is-this-an-index-or-a-base-pointer-or-what hassles. Over time, maybe that changed? The 68000 also had more registers, saving on some moving in-and-out of memory. Anyway, you don't need to learn SIMD stuff to get basic assembler principles.

Comment: @David - I can't believe I forgot (repressed) segmented addressing. This was bad enough in a high level language. There's segmented addressing again now, but it's a different thing, relating to virtual memory etc, that apps-level programmers shouldn't need to worry about.

Answer (score 7):

Assembly was the first language we learned in electronics school (back in the 1900s) and it seemed like a natural choice.  We worked our way up through our courses from discrete components, to resistor-transistor logic, logic gates, integrated circuits, processors, and on to programming in assembly.  A lot of the students in these classes had never programmed in any language before and they picked it right up.

So assembly *can* be a good choice for a first language if the right foundation is laid for the student.  For anyone whose goal is to be an applications or Web developer, however, I think assembly is probably too low-level a starting point.

Answer (score 7):

One thing is for sure, if the people, learning Assembly first, make it, they will be amazing programmers.

This reminds me of when I learned how to drive. My mom insisted

> **Learn on an automatic car until you gain confidence, and then you can drive our manual cars.**

The reasoning being she didn't want me to be distracted with more than I need to be, all at once.

Apply that to learning how to program, is it necessary to throw everything on a learner all at once?  They learn what a variable is at the same time they learn how much data they can store in what kind of register?

Over **half** my class failed our assembly class, and this was a group of people who, at that time, had considered themselves knowledgeable of programming for 2+ years.

My personal preference, if I had to learn everything again, would be to start with a language that does as much as possible for me.  Then, as I learn, move backwards towards the lower level languages.

Comment: I think this is good and sound advice. At some point it's important to be aware of bits and bytes and what the processor does with them but starting with them is a hugely wasteful endeavor because we have languages like ruby and python that are perfect for beginners and encourage excellent software engineering principles.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the instructor did a less-than-stellar job of teaching the assembly language class?

Comment: I think he did an amazing job.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a realistic idea, at least to those who are ready to make the extra effort?

No

> but one would have good understanding of the machine

Why is that advantageous?  Can you provide an example or a hint as to how this could be of any value?

> Advantages and disadvantages?

Advantages:  None.

Disadvantages:

- A clutter of random trivia about flags and states and registers and complex memory-addressing schemes and I/O devices and DMA and interrupts and clock cycles and stuff.  None of which helps understand modern VM-based languages and computing.
- A disconnect from actual problem-solving to which computers are actually applied.
- An divorce from end-users and the practical data and processing problems they need to solve.
- A needless spate of explanations of machine and virtual machine and compiler and interpreter and the entire stack of turtles holding up the world.
- A lot of detailed "this is the physical implementation of an 'object'" in the higher-level language that they eventually arrive at.
- A lot of detailed "this is how method functions are dispatched" in the higher-level language that they eventually arrive at.
- A lot of "this doesn't apply to 80386 but does apply to 80586 chipset" explanations.
- A lot of low-level OS API calls to make an ASM program do anything that appears similar to being useful by someone.

The point of a first programming language is not to master the chipset.

The point of a first programming language is to

1. Understand how to think about computing.
2. Understand how to do useful data processing.
3. Understand how to get something done.  Design -- code -- test.

Comment: Knowing how the machine works makes it easier to actually optimize many things at a higher level. It also makes it easier to understand many higher level concepts as well as avoid many security vulnerabilities (such as buffer overflows).

Comment: @Anto: "optimize many things at a higher level"  You mean data structures and algorithms?  The algorithms are always machine-independent.  "makes it easier to understand many higher level concepts"  False.  It's mental clutter.  "avoid many security vulnerabilities "  False.  Use a better language.  Those aren't advantages.  Those are a clutter of details.  Please provide a list of actual **advantages**.  i.e., more productive -- higher quality -- better fit with user expectations -- better value for the user.

Comment: @S.Lott - Maybe we disagree about this, but I think it helps in those ways. Sometimes you will have to write code in C, it maybe isn't even your choice. At such times, these vulnerabilities are risks which you should be aware of. You can optimize things as you are more aware of what it is to get something from memory to a register and then do something with that data. You are more aware of how things might affect performance. And, it has at least helped me understanding some of the higher level things, but humans differ, obviously.

Comment: @Anto: If you're talking about C, then assembler can help as a second language.  But that's not the question you asked.  Memory-to-register optimization is the job of OS, language and library.  Not developer.  It may have helped you, but you already knew something.  As a **first** language its useless details.  As a **later** language, I agree, it can help.  As a **first** language, it's a dreadful idea.

Comment: @S.Lott - Sure, that's not the point of my original question, but it could be advantageous to have these **before** you go to the higher level languages. Don't get me wrong, you make a valid point.

Comment: @Anti: "before you go to the higher level languages".  No.  It's clutter.  Higher-level languages are about solving user problems.  Anything that gets between user, problem and solution is technical clutter.  The point of a **first** language is to reduce technical clutter.  The point of an **advanced** language is to introduce technical clutter.

Comment: @S.Lott - As I said, you have a point.

Comment: -1 A lot of your disadvantages I consider advantages.  It is better to know how the low level works, before you use it from above.  Foundations are important.

Comment: @Orbling: Those aren't "foundations".  Logic, Data Structure, Algorithm, Finite Math are foundations.  Assembler is a chipset with all it's quirky failures and hack-arounds.

Comment: Assembler as a programming language, exposes you far better to data structure, logic and more low level foundations than the higher level languages do.  Both have a place, assembler could well be simpler to understand than the higher level languages, providing you did not try to achieve anything too complicated.  People should not be trying to do complex things at first.

Comment: @Orbling: "foundations" aren't chipset details and assembler quirks.  Assembler has it's place.  As a **first** language it's a dreadful idea.

Comment: The advantage of assembler is it demonstrates how a real computer works. You know. The thing everything actually *runs on*.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: While true, it doesn't convey any useful concept of what computing really is.  It's all detailed trivia about a specific chipset and a particular pile of hardware.  That kind of trivial knowledge is good for -- at most -- a few years.  Then Intel changes the chipset and some of that assembler knowledge is actually incorrect and detrimental.  As a **first** language it's unhelpful because it doesn't convey the enduring, timeless foundations of computing.  Logic.  Finite Math.  Data Structure.  Algorithm.

Comment: @S.Lott: There is so much more to it than those obscure details you are quoting, and the issues you bring up only come in to play in bigger projects, the like of which is not needed for a beginner.  It's *very* simple to code in assembler, you have to learn all about data, storage, sequential-branched-looped execution in the clearest possible way.  All points to recommend it as an instructional tool for absolute beginners.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think you have a flawed grasp of what we are talking about.  The assembler I learnt 17-18 years ago still helps me day-to-day conceptually, though I've not used that actual language personally for something like 12 years.

Comment: @S.Lott: I categorically disagree. My early experiences with Intel have pretty much translated into other architectures seamlessly, modulo bit-level details and exact names. a jump is a jump is a jump, no matter the architecture.

Comment: @S.Lott - Aren't Intel quite good at keeping backwards compability?

Comment: @Orbling: "assembler I learnt 17-18 years ago still helps me day-to-day conceptually"  Agreed.  "Intel have pretty much translated into other architectures".  Sadly, I'm too old to agree -- I used to work on 36-bit machines.  Really.  Some concepts don't map.  All this knowledge is **obviously helpful**.  But it should not be **first**.

Comment: @Anto: "Intel quite good at keeping backwards compability"  So you want to teach just the 8086 subset of the 80586 chipset?  That reinforces my point.  That kind of thing can't be **first** for teaching programming.

Comment: @S.Lott: Just to state, I did not mention Intel at all, I learnt that much later, I started with ARM - a much more enlightening RISC affair.

Comment: @S.Lott - No, but that means that you can very well use most of the old knowledge which you have gathered and add new knowledge over time. Look, high-level languages such as Python come with new versions over time, but old knowledge is still usable (and actually, Python broke backwards compatibility with v3)

Comment: @Orbling: "I did not mention Intel at all".  Apologies.  I pushed too many quotes together.

Comment: @Anto: I didn't mention Python as a good foundation.  I mentioned logic, finite math, algorithm and data structure.  Those do not change.  A language that conveys those things **first** conveys enduring knowledge.  Assembler first clutters it up with too much chipset trivia.

Comment: @S.Lott - I didn't mean Python in any special way, I just wanted to make the point that version 2.5 of Python is a subset of version 2.6 of Python (etc.), just as 8086 is a subset of 80586. The old knowledge still applies, you will just have to learn some new concepts and add those to your previous knowledge of the language.

Comment: @Anto: "learn some new concepts".  The point remains this.  The **enduring** concepts -- the things which should be taught **first** -- are neither language-specific or chipset-specific.  Assembler, however, has too much clutter to learn these enduring concepts.  A higher-level language is a better way to teach the **first** set of enduring, universal concepts.  Assembler can come later.  Language changes and compatibility-breaking can come later.  Much can come later.  But not **first**.

Comment: I'm bucking the trend here and +1-ing (after trying to balance out some conflicting views). I learned assembler early, and in a lot of ways I wish I had learned automata theory early instead. Mind you, that's not really a high-vs.low-level thing. Level of abstraction relates what you're doing relative to the foundation you're building upon, so theory is just a different kind of low-level really. Yet its an enduring low-level. So IMO Scheme is a very low level language (very close to the lambda calculus foundation) and as much as I hate to say it, may have more value than assembler.

Comment: I have to agree with @S.Lott.  He is not arguing that assembly language is not useful to learn as it seems like most of the comments are taking it.  He is merely arguing that it should not be _first_.  Something I agree with.

Answer (score 3):

If I was tasked to design a curriculum, I would have two courses running at the same time the first semester: asm + basic computer organization/architecture, and a SICP-based course founded in Scheme.  The second semester would be oriented around data structures and elementary algorithms in Scheme.

The second year would be a year-long project using one of Delphi, C++ or C#, focused on modern software design (OO design, some functional design, software engineering, version control, etc).

The effect should be to give an intense grounding in both the abstract and the practical, leading out to in-depth courses in the third and fourth years.

Answer (score 3):

I used to TA introductory computer science classes, and I think it's a bad idea.

1. Assembly uses both logic (if this goto that) and very difficult translations between concepts and numbers.  Intro CS students often struggle with just the logic (loops, if/else, boolean expressions), and really need to just deal with this before they also worry about which numbers mean what logical expressions.  Using higher-level languages abstracts out this logic for students who haven't had any reason to think that way before.
2. Intro CS classes are not necessarily being taken only by CS majors who will continue on with CS.  Often, they are also taken by other engineering majors and non-majors who are just "touring" an interesting subject for an elective.  Assembly is great for a foundation for hard-core, committed CS students, but doesn't give a very good overview of what programming often is for students considering the major or who are never going to take the major but want an introduction to the field; nor is it terribly useful on its own in most fields.
3. Higher-level languages make the core of actual programming work more transparent.  Assembly hits some key foundational topics - basic memory concepts, basic performance concepts, etc. - but doesn't really get into creating a maintainable, readable design, which is more important these days, IMO.  Early students seem to often have the old-fashioned "Real Programmers write code no one else can handle" ideas, and teaching a higher-level language helps teach that coding is a collaborative task and not just about being brilliant.

Having said that, I do think assembly / computer hardware should be a very early class - ideally, the first quarter in the major.  Have students get one high-level language under their belts, then jump into low-level hardware stuff right away before moving on to data structures - ideally in a language that requires management of memory.

Comment: Very well said -- I agree.  The first course needs to get to the point, show the end-to-end usefulness of the skills being learned, and fire the imagination: "Gosh! I can program?  Now what else can I do with this new skill..."   Agree also that the best time for assembly language is after one higher level language.  That motivates looking "under the hood" at how the computer is actually understanding the higher level stuff.  Seeing assembly language for the first time after a higher level language leaves another powerful impact: the student encounters electronics, chips, sensors, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Assembly was my second language, right after BASIC.  However, when I was learning it was a different time.  My Commodore 64 had other languages available, but if you wanted anything to seem fast, or wanted to do more than one thing at a time, you needed to learn assembly language and how to work with interrupts.  The Graphic Environment Operating System (GEOS) that gave the Commodore a windowing system was also all assembly.  It was by and large the best assembly API I have ever seen.  It was also the only platform I used where you could style your code.  That's right, you could use italics and different font sizes--something that proved useful for reading the comments.

I learned a lot about how the Commodore worked, but the Motorolla chip had a very simple opcode set.  It's not too difficult to keep less than 255 opcodes separate from each other.  I was *not* able to parlay my experience on the Motorolla 6510 chip to programming for the Intel 8086.  The chips and system architectures were too different.  I imagine I would have had the same trouble moving up to the Amiga's Motorolla 68000 chip as well.

In short, I have to wholeheartedly disagree with anyone who says Assembly should be a good first language.  Here's why:

- You have no inherent structure, no common way of breaking down functionality in an application.  This is the very thing that makes higher level languages so useful.
- You have to know useless things like how to call a method in a library correctly.  When the library was created by C that means manipulating the stack (better get everything in the right order), but in another language it might mean setting registers.  These are all things taken care of by a compiler or an interpreter--and you can't optimize them.
- Your code can *not* be used on another chip, and very likely will break with a different hardware platform.

These days assembly language is used to speed up certain finite actions where hand-crafted assembly would be quicker than compiler generated assembly.  The main structure of the application is done in a higher level language like C, C++, etc.  Of course, assembly programming would become very important if you start writing compilers.  How many of us do that?

Answer (score 1):

I took assembly in my senior year of high school.  I had taken classes in Java, Pascal, C and C++ already, and wasn't proficient at any of them and I really sucked at Assembly - was the only person taking the class in a distance learning program at the community college, took me a month or two before anyone could even get the compiler working for me.

I don't think it's necessary or wise to learn assembly language first, but it is smart to learn the stuff they teach you in the first few weeks of assembly, about how the processor works and some of the debug tricks.   That stuff I found very interesting and enlightening as a neophyte.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it couldn't be done, although how good of an idea it is totally depends on the crowd you would teach it too. Somebody whose end goal is to be a web developer would probably get bored and might quit as it wouldn't give them the immediate satisfaction of creating something that Python, Ruby, etc. would. If they want to eventually work on hardware or other low level projects then I think it would be an ok start (provided that you give enough of a computer architecture background for it to make sense). I think it could help the people write better code in the future, although I think it would be more difficult than learning other languages to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think assembly language is only going to make sense if you focus on things like:

- Memory management techniques
- HW IO (especially timing and performance related challenges)
- CPU features - in particular, security features

Without a focus in this area, it's just a simplistic language that will tend to teach bad organization habits.  Machine level coding is good to have in the tool kit to know how things work, but it isn't a good first language.

I would get somebody interested in a higher level language.  Then teach C++; then assembly with a focus on how C++ compilers generate assembly code.  Understanding v-tables and other higher level language features will go a long way to help the developer think about how languages really work than just filing the information under 'magic.'